# How to console.log data from an API call in this situation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

In getData() function, I'm console.logging data to see if it set in the state properly after an asynchronous call. It's returning Array[] which I'm guessing means that the data set but console.log is running before the fetch finishes.

The console.log in the useEffect works properly although it will log it twice.

Is there a way to console.log inside of getData() function or is it the proper way to do it in the useEffect?

useEffect console.log runs twice because I'm guessing once after the data is retrieved and set into state, and then after it's set, it console logs it again after the re-render.

```
const TestComponent = () => {
    // State for Data
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    // URL for Data
    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20'
    // Retrieve Data - Function
    const getData = async() => {
        const { results } = await (await fetch(url)).json()
        setData(results)
        console.log(data)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
        console.log(data)
    },[])
return (JSX)
```

Comment: the best choice is to stop using `console.log()` and to use an actual debugger - either in the browser or an IDE.

Comment: Yes, please read react life cycles once again, how they correlate with hooks, the second parameter in use effect and when does what run w.r.t. componentDidMount and  componentDidUpdate. Also learn about why JavaScript is a non-blocking event driven language essentially learn the event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run an effect whenever state `data` changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(data.length) {
    console.log(data)
  }
}, [data])
```

Comment: This causes an infinite loop. Please, update your answer

Comment: this won't cause an infinite loop, the data will get logged whenever it changes and I guess according to the question the API call will run only once on mount so the data will be changed just once

If this is not the case, can you please explain a little so I can update the answer

Comment: Its just logging the state not updating I guess

Comment: After troubleshooting you were right. So I don't need the if statement just the console.log(data) and data in the dependency array. I had to remove getData() out of the useEffect and instead use a button to call it. 
The infinite loop is caused if I run getData() in the useEffect

Comment: I'm glad it helped.
the if condition is for unnecessary logging I use most of the time to only get log when the data is available. Its up to you to add it as it don't has any effect other than this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getData = async() => {
        const { results } = await (await fetch(url)).json()
        setData(results)
        console.log(data)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
        console.log(data)
    },[])
```

`useEffect` only execute once, you are seeing `console.log` twice simply because one in `getData` while another in `useEffect`